# Unity has extreme lag while deleting trees from terrain

Tags: unity, performance, terrain, lag, tree

So I have a terrain with sections of water in it. I just placed a whole bunch of trees in the scene with mass place. However, it spawned trees in the water which I obviously want to remove. But when I remove the trees, there a delay of a couple of seconds before it actually deletes them. This is so incredibly frustrating because my map is 8km x 8km so for me to have to go around every area of water and cliff and click, wait a few seconds and move on is going to take all day. Why can't I just click and drag without lag?

Comment: This might be a good case to bring to the [Unity Bug Report](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting) or [Feature Feedback](https://feedback.unity3d.com/?_ga=1.18752505.1960338090.1423240788) systems. It might or might not have a user-side fix, depending on what the root cause is.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? I use to have a similar issue working with large terrain on a 4GB system

Comment: @Gnemlock I have 16gb of RAM, i7 4770k, gtx 1080 super clocked, it's pretty safe to say that it's not my system

Comment: how do you tell unity to remove the trees? is it `foreach(tree in toberemoved) remove(tree);` cause that will cause a O(n²)  time complexity unless unity uses a hashset to store them.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I meant in the editor

Comment: Personally for me even on a high end machine unity can just be slow deleting or adding a lot of trees. I just deal with it at this point. Doesn't seem to be fixable.